# Adding Automate Unique Indexes on Relationships (CYPHER, Neo4j)

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, unique, relationships

I have a set of relationships in Neo4j on which I want to add unique indexes in an automated way, does anybody know how that can be done automatically?

Also would be nice to have an example on how to generate automated unique values to associate with new entities in a query. Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice to see an example of input data, the desired result and how do you try to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Neo4j has "automatic" [indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html) for nodes, but not relationships. You *can* create [legacy indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-indexes.html) for relationships, but they are no longer the preferred way to index, and relationships will not be added automatically to such an index. You are responsible for "manually" adding nodes/relationships to legacy indexes. In neo4j 3.0, there are [APOC procedures for manual indexes](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_manual_indexes) that you can call from Cypher, which makes this more convenient, but it is still not "automatic".

   *NOTE: APOC procedures must be [installed on the neo4j server](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_build_install_apoc_procedures) before you can use them.*
2. In neo4j 3.0, your Cypher code can now use [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) to get [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s. For example, to get a single UUID:

   ```
   CALL apoc.create.uuid YIELD uuid
   ```

Comment: thanks for the comment. Are you sure this adds unique indexes on relationships? I think it only does on nodes. Am I wrong?

Comment: So after a bit o googl-ing it seems like a UNIQUE constraint is yet implemented for relationships.

Comment: You would not need a uniqueness constraint if you always used a newly generated UUID as the value you put in the legacy relationship index. Also, uniqueness constraints are only for the newer automatic indexes, and have nothing to do with legacy indexes.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like at present, [CONSTRAINTs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-constraints), and therefore unique indexing, can only be applied on nodes. I don't know if there is a plan to extend this feature to relationships.

Comment: You would not need a uniqueness constraint if you always used a newly generated UUID as the value you put in a *legacy* relationship index. In fact, uniqueness constraints are only for the newer automatic indexes, and have nothing to do with legacy indexes.

Comment: I will look into it - you don't provide enough information in your comment. I can't make sense of what you are saying. Thanks for the comment though. I will move the accepted response to your answer once I look into what you are saying.

Comment: I once more - thanks for clarifying. Following your comment, this [blog here](http://jexp.de/blog/2015/04/on-neo4j-indexes-match-merge/) explains everything nicely.